# R addPolygons function

Tags: r, leaflet, r-sp

I am trying to add some polygons to a map, but I'm not sure why my code is not working. I've used the same code before on other .shp files, and it works fine. I obtained the spatial file from here: http://library.queensu.ca/geo/health_regions. It is under Ontario->Local Health Integrated Networks -> 2006 -> Boundary Files.

```
  lhin<- readOGR("lhin_divisions/HR035B08.shp",layer = "HR035B08")
  leaflet() %>% addTiles()%>%setView(lng=-81,lat=45,zoom=6)
  %>%addPolygons(data=lhin,stroke=TRUE, weight=1, col='red')
```

I feel like I am missing something simple, but I can't figure out what?

The resulting map should have the boundaries shown here:http://library.queensu.ca/madgic/free/health_regions/2005/images/lhin_ont.pdf

Comment: where is this data=provinces coming from? did you load provinces?

Comment: Sorry that shoud read lhin!

Comment: your color is missing

Comment: adding col='red' didn't change anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this work. You can change the tile color, I just used a black and white since I did not know what I was looking for. The shapefile was in utm with no projection. So I set the projection and converted into longlat.

```
proj4string(lhin) <- CRS("+proj=utm +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")
lhin <- spTransform(lhin, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84"))
leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles("Stamen.Toner") %>% addPolygons(data=lhin,stroke=TRUE, weight=1, color = ~"red")
```

[image]

Comment: This seems great! Two questions though: why did you need to apply those two functions (CRS and spTransform), and why does the map not correctly overlay on top of Ontario?  Sorry, I'm very new to the world of maps!

Comment: Does it have something to do with the new projection?

Comment: it was utm and it needed to be longlat. Next time just verify the projection of your shapefile. It was probably working before because they were already on longlat

Comment: Oh I see, but why does the map appear in the wrong part of the world?

Comment: I don't know where it's supposed to be, but in general we also have to setfor utm the epsg as lhin <- spTransform(lhin, CRS("+init=epsg:2957")) 2957 is for western Canada, you will have to set for your location.

Comment: you will have to do this on your own, the map works you just need to set the right projection.

Comment: hmm I'm still rather confused. I have changed one of the statements in your code to proj4string(lhin) <- CRS("+proj=lcc +ellps=GRS80  +datum=NAD83 +units=m") because that is the projection specified in the documentation of the file. However, I am unable to figure out what CRS() has to do with where the image is plotted. My file is a map of Ontario subdivions, so I want it to be mapped on top of Ontario

Comment: I still used readOGR() to read the file in as it does come with a projection. I then applied spTransform(lhin, CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")) as you suggested. Now the map is placed correctly over Ontario.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you!! and thanks for accepting the answer!